# When should one include the error handler on an Observable?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm confused about general good practice when it comes to error handling. For example, if I'm already catching the error in my service, do I still need to include the error handler in my subscription?

Here's my http method in my service. As you can see it calls catchError:

```
  deleteTask(id: number): Observable<any>{

    return this.http.delete(this.tasksUrl+'/'+`${id}`)
    .pipe(
      catchError(this.handleError)
    );
  }

  private handleError(res: HttpErrorResponse | any) {
    console.error(res.error || res.body.error);
    return observableThrowError(res.error || 'Server error');
  }
```

And in my component:

```
delete(id: number){
    this.deleteService.deleteTask(id).subscribe(
      (val) => {
         /*post processing functionality not relevant to this question 
         */
       }
    );
  }
```

In the angular documentation https://angular.io/guide/observables the error handler is described as optional:

```
myObservable.subscribe(
  x => console.log('Observer got a next value: ' + x),
  err => console.error('Observer got an error: ' + err),
  () => console.log('Observer got a complete notification')
);
```

So in my example, would including the error handler on my subscription add anything to my code? Like if I did:

```
delete(id: number){
    this.deleteService.deleteTask(id).subscribe(
      (val) => {
         /*post processing functionality not relevant to this question 
         */
       },
      err => console.error('Observer got an error: ' + err)
    );
```

Would it catch anything my catchError didn't catch? It almost feels like it would be good practice to always include the error handler, so I don't know why it's marked as optional? When should one use the subscription error handler vs other forms of error handling?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's all about how you want to handle error in your application,

1. if you want to throw a fancy error instead of the actual error comming back from server, you can have a error handler in service end and who ever consume your service will get the fancy error instead of actual error.

```js
  // copied from your question
  deleteTask(id: number): Observable<any>{

    return this.http.delete(this.tasksUrl+'/'+`${id}`)
    .pipe(
      catchError(this.handleError)
    );
  }

  private handleError(res: HttpErrorResponse | any) {
    console.error(res.error || res.body.error);
    return observableThrowError(res.error || 'Server error');
  }
```

2. if not, you dont need to handle error in your service code, let the consumer(service/component) handle it.

```js
  deleteTask(id: number): Observable<any>{
    return this.http.delete(this.tasksUrl+'/'+`${id}`);
  }

  // component
  ...
   this.service.deleteTask(id).subscribe(success,(err) => {
      // example
      alert(err.message);
   });
  ...
```

3. To handle common http errors (500, 401, 403, 404) you can write a `HttpInterceptor`, so that you dont need to write the error handling logic everywhere.

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { 
  HttpEvent, HttpRequest, HttpHandler, HttpInterceptor, HttpErrorResponse 
} from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable, throwError } from 'rxjs';
import { catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable()
export class MyAppHttpInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

  intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {

    return next.handle(request).pipe(
      catchError((error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
        if (error.status === 401) {
          // redirect to login page
        } else {
          return throwError(error);
        }
      })
    );    
  }
}
```

4. if you want to log the errors to server or if you want to show a custom console or error notification over the screen on development mode or for debugging, you can create a global error handler service extending the existing `ErrorHandler` servcie in angular.

```js
    import { ErrorHandler } from '@angular/core';

    @Injectable()
    export class GlobalErrorHandler implements ErrorHandler {

      handleError(error) {
        // your custom error handling logic    
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Would it catch anything my catchError didn't catch?

No, you are just passing the same error through. But if your subscription doesn't have an error handler you will get an exception if you don't handle it. So you should either have an error handler on your subscription or pass an observable with no data.

```js
const { throwError, of } = rxjs;
const { catchError } = rxjs.operators;

throwError('error').pipe(catchError(error => {
  console.log('Caught error - ', error);
  return of(null);
})).subscribe(val => { console.log('No error handler needed'); });

throwError('error').pipe(catchError(e => {
  console.log('Caught error - ', e);
  return throwError(e);
})).subscribe(val => {}, error => { console.log('Subscription handled error - ', error); });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/6.5.3/rxjs.umd.min.js"></script>
```